# Track APP Installs from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm following documentation as states:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#advanced

- Specifically: Measure App Installs

However, I did the following code:

```
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp( this, APPLICATION_ID_FACEBOOK );
```

However, in dashboard, it doesn't detect the install:
[image]

Any tips?

LogCat outputs the following:

> FacebookException: No attribution id returned from the Facebook application

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Solved.

Basically for whoever faces this:

1. FACEBOOK APP must be installed in device.
2. USER must be logged in.

Thats it.

=)

Answer (score 0):

Another great but hidden hint is to enable verbose logging via

```
FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(APP_EVENTS)
```

The output is actually very helpful and even contains error analysis and descriptions.